# Making a single page blog in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I've been bashing my head against wordpress for the past couple of day trying to solve this, I'm trying to create a single page site / landing page but using wordpress to display latest news stories, but have links to the previous three news articles.

Everything is working apart from being able to move from the first 3 post using previous and next links at the bottom of the page. when I click to move to the past news stories it reloads the page altering the query string correctly but the posts aren't updated and I can't move past the 2nd page.

I've used this webpage http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2008/04/19/paging-and-custom-wordpress-loops/ as a basis for my page but following the directions hasn't solved my problem.

The markup I've used in the page is here http://codepad.org/dliQIwJR

I've configured all the setting inside of wordpress, I've set the page up in reading setting to Front page under static page.

many thanks for any help offered.

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: can you provide the site url?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the "showposts" parameter. Try replacing with "posts_per_page=3" instead. showposts argument has been removed.

see https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters for the specifics, and that page overall for WP_Query reference in general.

```
posts_per_page (int) - number of post to show per page (available with Version 2.1, replaced showposts parameter).
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question 100% correctly, but, try "page" instead of "paged" at line 40. I had a similar problem with a site and somehow this solved it for me. Specifically, I used:

```
    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    } else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('page');
    } else {
        $paged = 1;
    }
```