# Wordpress custom post template page/2 loop not working

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a loop in the sidebar of a custom template and it works perfectly when the page is loaded. The page is -

http://ere.doneready.com/senior-consultants

However the loop (which shows the list of names) does not work when I click the "next" button i.e. this page -

http://ere.doneready.com/senior-consultants/page/2/

Can anyone help? The following is the code I use -

```
 <div id="people-sidebar-content">

<div id="custom-search-form-for-people">    
    <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
        <div id="custom-search-form-label"><label for="s" class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'SEARCH' ); ?></label></div>
        <span id="search-box-box"><input class="search-box" type="text" name="s" id="s" /></span>
        <span id="search-box-button"><input type="image" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" SRC="http://www.doneready.com/ere/wp-content/themes/ere/images/search_button.png" HEIGHT="17" WIDTH="20" BORDER="0" ALT="Submit Form"></span>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="people-sidebar-content-usable" class="senior-consultants-active">

<div id="sidebar-for-people">
<a class="directors" href="http:/www.ere.doneready.com/directors/">Directors</a><br />
<a class="finance-admin" href="http:/www.ere.doneready.com/finance-and-admin/">Finance & Admin</a><br />
<a class="senior-consultants" href="http:/www.ere.doneready.com/senior-consultants/">Senior Consultants</a><br />
<div id="actual-people-list">
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args=array(
   'post_type'=>'staff',
   'posts_per_page' => 99,
   'paged'=>$paged,
   'staff_categories'=>'Senior Consultants'
);
$temp1 = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
?>
<div class="actual-people-list-single">
<a href ="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'staff_short_name', true ) ); ?>
</a>
</div>
<?php
endwhile; endif;
/* PageNavi at Bottom */
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $temp1;
wp_reset_query(); 
?>
</div>
<a class="consultants" href="http:/www.ere.doneready.com/consultants/">Consultants</a><br />
<a class="technical-support" href="http:/www.ere.doneready.com/technical-support/">Technical Support</a>
</div>

</div><!--END PEOPLE-SIDEBAR-CONTENT-USABLE-->
</div><!--END PEOPLE-SIDEBAR-CONTENT-->

</div><!--END CONTENT CONTAINER-->
</div><!--END PAGE-WRAP-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, try to search the archives at least semi-extensively first because many variations of this question exist. Here's a link to my answer to a very similar question, it worked for me, it might work for you:

[Making a single page blog in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146515/making-a-single-page-blog-in-wordpresss/15517916#15517916)

Comment: Thanks CL75, I did search a lot but could not find a solution. Being a novice PHP programmer does not help either :(

Comment: Did you try the solution I suggested in the link? What happened? The best way to get answers here is to post as much info, work and code as possible. Otherwise you'll just get a lot of elitist attitude :)

Comment: Hi CL75, Thanks. I managed to solve it using a different loop.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I used a new loop and the code looks like this now -

```
<div id="people-sidebar-content">

<div id="custom-search-form-for-people">    
    <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
        <div id="custom-search-form-label"><label for="s" class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'SEARCH' ); ?></label></div>
        <span id="search-box-box"><input class="search-box" type="text" name="s" id="s" /></span>
        <span id="search-box-button"><input type="image" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" SRC="http://www.doneready.com/ere/wp-content/themes/ere/images/search_button.png" HEIGHT="17" WIDTH="20" BORDER="0" ALT="Submit Form"></span>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="people-sidebar-content-usable" class="senior-consultants-active">

<div id="sidebar-for-people">
<a class="directors" href="http:/www.ere.com.my/directors/">Directors</a><br />
<a class="senior-consultants" href="http:/www.ere.com.my/senior-consultants/">Senior Consultants</a><br />
<div id="actual-people-list">
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'staff', 'staff_categories'=>'Senior Consultants', 'posts_per_page' => 50 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
<div class="actual-people-list-single">
<a href ="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'staff_short_name', true ) ); ?>
</a>
</div>
<?php
endwhile;
?>
<?php
wp_reset_query(); 
?>
</div>
<a class="consultants" href="http:/www.ere.com.my/consultants/">Consultants</a><br />
<a class="technical-support" href="http:/www.ere.com.my/technical-support/">Technical Support</a>
<a class="finance-admin" href="http:/www.ere.com.my/finance-and-admin/">Finance & Admin</a><br />
</div>
```